# Не работает Wi-Fi на Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: wifi, raspberry-pi, модули, raspbian

После инсталляции Lite Raspbian на Raspberry Pi 3, начал его настройку для использования в качестве Wi-Fi роутера (благо в 3 версии Wi-Fi встроенный).

Установил все обновления (apt update && apt upgrade -y && apt full-upgrade -y && rpi-update && reboot)

После перезагрузки, Wi-Fi перестал работать, сам wlan0 не определяется.
Вот результат вывода dmesg связанный с Wi-Fi

> dmesg | egrep brcm
>
> [   57.612013] usbcore: registered new interface driver brcmfmac
>  [
>   57.772229] brcmfmac mmc1:0001:1: Direct firmware load for brcm/brcmfmac43430-sdio.txt failed with error -2
>  [   58.843390]
>   brcmfmac: brcmf_sdio_htclk: HT Avail timeout (1000000): clkctl
>   0x50
>  [   59.846276] brcmfmac: brcmf_sdio_htclk: HT Avail timeout
>   (1000000): clkctl 0x50

Как это исправить?

Comment: Проблема "решилась" путём заморозки пакета firmware-brcm80211 в версии 0.43+rpi4 отпоследующих обновлений.